# Compass watch hangs

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I've been successfully using `compass watch` on the command line to automatically recompile my CSS whenever an SCSS file changes.

Now, it is hanging my system. It is taking up more than 10 GB of RAM. I've tried rolling back to earlier commits in my repo, and the problem continues. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your paths are correct and your files are correct. Sometimes corrupted images may cause this problem.

Comment: Yes, apparently I had recently added a file to my /images/ folder that was a corrupt .png file.  When I replaced it with a valid .png file, Compass worked again. Thanks!